# Convergence of expectation and its implications

Tags: statistics, expected-value, weak-convergence

I understand that $T_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}t$ **does not** imply that $\mathbb E[T_n]$ converges (including to $t$). At the same time, we know that convergence in probability, implies convergence in distribution. Accordingly $T_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}t\implies T_n\xrightarrow{(d)}t$, and considering the following [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) definition

$$T_n\xrightarrow{(d)}T\iff\mathbb E[f(T_n)]\rightarrow\mathbb E[f(T)],\forall f\text{continuous, and bounded}$$

I wonder if by replacing $T=t$ and $f(\cdot)$ is an identity function, it is correct stating that $T_n\xrightarrow{(d)}t\iff\mathbb E[T_n]\rightarrow t$, which seems really off, and I am sure I probably misunderstood the definition of the convergence in distribution. Can someone shed some light?

Another doubt I have is whether I can say that if $\mathbb E[T_n]\rightarrow t$ and $\text{var}(T_n)\rightarrow 0$, then $T_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}t$? Intuitively, I would say that [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_statement) is sufficient to prove, but I wonder if there is more to it.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(|T_n-\mathbb E[T_n]|>\varepsilon)=\mathbb P(|T_n-t|>\varepsilon)\le\frac{\text{var}(T_n)}{\varepsilon^2}\rightarrow0$$

Thanks!

Comment: (1) The identity function is not necessarily bounded. (2) Yes, but your argument needs a bit of work. Delete the limit. Chebyshev applies to the first probability, then take limits. Now think about how to get from $T_n - E(T_n)$ to $E T_n - t$. Addition is a continuous operation!

Comment: Thanks @Galton, I guess that (1) I was missing the *bounded* requirement, and (2) I think I understand what you mean. Will work it out and get back to you.

Comment: @Galton, does this sound right? $\mathbb P(|T_n-\mathbb E[T_n]|\ge\varepsilon)\le\frac{\text{var}(T_n)}{\varepsilon^2}\rightarrow 0$, which means that $T_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb p}\mathbb E[T_n]$, which in turn $\rightarrow t$. Accordingly, $T_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}t$?

Comment: Almost. Your second limit has an n subscript in the limit, which can’t be true. Write $T_n=(T_n -ET_n) + ET_n$. The object in parentheses converges to zero in P and the second Summand coverges to $t$. Have you learned a result that allows you to combine sums of convergent objects, like the continuous mapping theorem or the Slutsky Lemma?

Comment: Hi @Galton, sorry I did not catch to which *second* limit you were referring to. What I meant is that Chebyshev's inequality proves that $T_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}\mathbb E[T_n]$ and that $\mathbb E[T_n]\rightarrow t$, because this was the initial assumption. I saw the CMP and Slutsky's Theorem, but I did not feel the need for using it here... but again, maybe I jumped too soon to the conclusion.

Comment: You are taking a limit as $n\to\infty$, so a statement like $x_n \to y_n$ makes no sense because $y_n$ still depends on $n$ after taking $n\to\infty$. As for the Slutsky lemma, how do you justify that $T_n  \to^p t$ from $T_n - E T_n \to^p 0$ and $E T_n \to t$?

Comment: @Galton, you are saying that since $T_n-\mathbb E[T_n]\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}0$ and $\mathbb E[T_n]\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}t$, then in accordance with the CMT $(T_n-\mathbb E[T_n])+\mathbb E[T_n]\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}0+t$ converges to t, right?

Comment: Yes! CMT or any other argument that lets you string together convergence in probability statements